# Making a GeoTIFF be able to be layered over another GeoTIFF in an application like QGIS with only the black pixels covering it

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio

Right now my result is :

[image: Current Result]

What I need is:

[image: Needed Result]

The difference between the two:

[image: Difference]

Multiband.tif:
[image: Multiband.tif]

I'm currently using Python and the rasterio library with the following code:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import numpy as np
import rasterio

# Open the multi-band GeoTIFF file
with rasterio.open('multiband.tif') as src:
    # Read the specified band (e.g., band 1)
    band = src.read(4)

    # Get the metadata for the source file
    meta = src.meta

# Update the metadata to indicate a single-band file
meta.update(count=1)

# Create a new numpy array with the same shape as the band, filled with zeros
new_band = np.zeros(band.shape, dtype=band.dtype)

# Find the black pixels in the band (where the pixel value is 0)
black_pixels = np.where(band == 0)

# Set the corresponding pixels in the new band to 1
new_band[black_pixels] = 1

# Set all non-black pixels to 0
new_band[new_band != 1] = 0

# Write the new single-band GeoTIFF file
with rasterio.open('singleband.tif', 'w', **meta) as dst:
    # Write the new band as the single band
    dst.write(new_band, 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store non-black pixels before assigning 1 to the black pixels.

```
....

# Find the black pixels in the band (where the pixel value is 0)
black_pixels = np.where(band == 0)

# Find the non-black pixels in the band (where the pixel value is not 0)
non_black_pixels = np.where(band != 0)

# Set the corresponding pixels in the new band to 1
new_band[black_pixels] = 1

# Set all non-black pixels to 0
new_band[non_black_pixels] = 0

....
```